# Keras autoencoder outputting wrong shape

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to build a deep convolutional autoencoder in Keras, but it keeps outputting the wrong shape.

Code:

```
def build_network(input_shape):
    input_input =  Input(shape=input_shape)

    #Encode
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(input_input)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    #Decode
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) 
    x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
    decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    autoencoder = Model(input_input, decoded)
    return autoencoder


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(build_network((1, 32, 32)).layers[-1].output)
```

I expect the output shape to be the same as the input shape, but it is instead `(8, 32, 1)` for `(1, 32, 32)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `print(build_network((32,32,1)).layers[-1].output)`. Or if you want to use channel first than you need to change model like this,

```
def build_network(input_shape):
    input_input =  Input(shape=input_shape)

    #Encode
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding = 'same')(input_input)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

    #Decode
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2),data_format="channels_first")(x)
    x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2),data_format="channels_first")(x)
    x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x) 
    decoded = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2),data_format="channels_first")(x)
    # decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
    autoencoder = Model(input_input, decoded)
    return autoencoder

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(build_network((1, 32, 32)).layers[-1].output)
```

Because in [`UpSampling2D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#upsampling2d), default is "channels_last".

Comment: @ZeroMaxinumXZ glad to help :)